# Update deep nested state (normalized) in react redux

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, state, immutability

I am trying to create a flight search application in React / Redux, where in the main screen all my flight results will be shown, and in the sidebar, different kind of filters as checkboxes are displayed. (as an example, see [this example](http://www.chaser.nl/zoekresultaten/?uq=S7GMiRzmqxBVQk8bHlac&tt=Retour&na=1&nc=0&ni=0&dd=20160903&rd=20160910&ori=Nederland%20en%20omstreken%20(NL)&des=London%20-%20All%20airports,%20Verenigd%20Koninkrijk%20(LON)&prefnonstop=false)

The filters are grouped by types, e.g. departure stations, arrival stations, departure times etc. All filterelements are created in one normalized nested state, where each element has the following properties:

```
"type": "airlines",           // this is the group type 
"checked": true,              // will be switched true or false
"label": "Brittish Airways"   // this is the display label
```

When I click one of the checkboxes in my React view, the following action will be fired:

```
export function filterFlightOffers(item, index) {
    return {
        type: 'FILTER_FLIGHT_OFFERS',
        grouptype,
        id
    }
}
```

I would like my redux reducer to update the state (switch checked value) and return the new state (e.g. immutable). Looking at the examples online, I react solutions like copying new state with a spread operator, e.g. ...state and update the spefic element with the switched checked item, e.g. {[action.id]: checked, !checked}.

But I just cant get it to work, I think due to the fact that I have a deep nested state.. Therefore I removed the action and reducer complexity and made a simple jsfiddle which should just console.log a new immutable 'changed' state.

Is there someone who could help me out?

http://jsfiddle.net/gzco1yp7/4/

Thank you!

Comment: why are you nesting `...state[action.id]` inside `state[action.id]` ? It would be a bit easier to help if you could explain what is on your action and what you're trying to do with it. For example, maybe you are trying to update `action.id` exercise with `action.exercise`. What you have here and the state you have in your fiddle don't line up at all.

Comment: O, I am really sorry. The code displayed in the app has nothing to do with my real code indeed. It was just a copy from an online example to show the principe. The code I am working on is in the fiddle. For making things easier, I have removed the whole action. Only looking for a solution to copy the initial state and update a specific deep element in it... I will update my initial question accordingly.

Comment: No worries, between these 2 examples there is no clear picture of what you are trying to do. If you can clearly describe *what* you are trying to change in the state and how ( as in what are you passing in your actions to your reducers), I can show you how to do it with immutable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your state looks something like this:

```
{    
  result: [1,2,3,4],
  entities: {
    searchitems: {
      1: {
        "type": "matchAirlines",
        "checked": false,
        "label": "Match airlines"
      }, 
      2: {
        "type": "airlines",
        "checked": true,
        "label": "Air France"
      },
      3: {
        "type": "airlines",
        "checked": true,
        "label": "Brittish Airways"
      }
    }, 
    counts:
      1: { "count": 2001 }, 
      2: { "count": 579 },
      3: { "count": 554 } 
    } 
  }
}
```

...your reducer could look like this:

```
function reducer(state, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FILTER_FLIGHT_OFFERS':
      return {
        ...state,
        entities: {
          ...state.entities,
          searchItems: Object.keys(state.entities.searchItems).reduce((newItems, id) => {
            const oldItem = state.entities.searchItems[id];
            if (oldItem.type === action.groupType) {
              newItems[id] = { ...oldItem, checked: id === action.id };
            } else {
              newItems[id] = oldItem;
            }
            return newItems;
          }, {})
        }
      };
  }

  return state;
}
```

This is made simpler if you use [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) and create a reducer just for your searchItems. And lodash can also simplify things:

```
import mapValues from 'lodash/mapValues';

function searchItemsReducer(state, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FILTER_FLIGHT_OFFERS':
      return mapValues(state, (oldItem, id) => (
        oldItem.type === action.groupType 
          ? { ...oldItem, checked: id === action.id };
          : oldItem
      ));
  }

  return state;
}
```

Comment: Thnx, especially the second advice made me think... why not make my state a lot more easier. I converted to a simple array of objects and am now able to use .map and .filter to get things to work. Many thanks for your answer!